# Replace all values that do not contain a specific string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe:

```
df
Name    Country     Amount_1    Amount_2
Neo     Monaco      100.2       100.2
Nord    Myland      100.2       100.2
Nemo    Marek       100.2       100.2
Novak   Mozart      100.2       100.2
```

I want to replace all entries in Country column which does not contain the string "land"

I am using the below code for the same:

```
df['Country'] = np.where(~df['Country'].str.contains("land"), "Others", df['Country'])
```

But i am getting the below error:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'
```

If i remove the .str from the above code then i get the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

Below is the dataftype for df:

```
Name        object
Country     object
Amount_1    float64
Amount_2    float64
dtype: object
```

Not sure what i am missing here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could happen due to `Nan` in your `Country` column.

Please pass **`na=False`** parameter in [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['Country'] = np.where(~df['Country'].str.contains("land", na=False), "Others", df['Country'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The data may contains missing Country, i.e`NaN`. Use `== True` in the condition instead of negation:

```
df['Country'] = np.where(df['Country'].str.contains("land") == True, "Others", df['Country'])
```

or simpler, swap the replacements:

```
df['Country'] = np.where(df['Country'].str.contains("land"), df['Country'], 'Others')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me. Probably your complete dataset has `NaN's` somewhere, or does it also not work with your sample dataset?

You could also try without Numpy:

```
df.loc[~df['Country'].str.contains('land'), 'Country'] = "Others"
```